# How do I use a BSS var to move string into register NASM

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to move a string into a BSS var, I've tried various methods but I have a feeling that unless I hardcode the string or use a read to grab the string I'm fighting a futile battle, the problem I'm having is although I can get the text data into the right register more data accompanies it which trashes the output and some how trashes the value of vdlen (if I directly assign a value to ecx in WriteFile the proper length is put however attempting to use vdlen causes it to way off radar)

How do I get the right results (ie "Hello!" in "text.txt") ?

```
section .bss
      vdata resw 10
      vdlen resb 3
      vfd resb 1
      vfn resb 15
      err resb 2
section .text
      mov eax,vfn
      mov dword [eax],'test'
      mov dword [eax+3], '.txt'
      mov ebx,vdata
      mov dword [ebx], 'Hell'
      mov dword [ebx+3],'o!'
      mov ecx,vdlen
      mov [ecx], 0x03h
      jmp WriteFile
ProgramEnd:
      mov eax,1
      mov ebx,[err]
      int 80h
WriteFile:
      mov eax,5   ;Syscall for open()
      mov ebx,vfn
      mov ecx, 65  ; mode Write-only Create
      mov edx, 420 ; permissions rw-r-r
      int 80h      ; Linux Kernel Interrupt

      mov [vfd],eax ; get file descriptor

      mov eax,4   ;Syscall for write()
      mov ebx,[vfd] ; FD argument
      mov ecx,[vdata] ; this is where my issue is
      mov edx,[vdlen] ; length of vdata
      int 80h

      mov [err],eax
      jmp ProgramEnd
```

Comment: DWORD are **four** bytes and "Hello!" are **six** bytes, so every '3' in your source is wrong. `mov [ecx], 0x03h` doesn't assemble.

Comment: Why can't you just declare the string in the `.data` section?

Comment: Also, the buffer for `vfd` and `err` seems too short. `eax` and `ebx` are 4 bytes long.

Comment: Michael I wanted to see if it was indeed possible to do it though I realize that it would be more convenient to just declare all strings in .data, ahh Thanks rkhb, MikeCAT are you saying that I can only hold 4 bytes in eax/ebx/ecx/edx/  ?

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

After the extremely helpful advice provided by rkbh and MikeCat to the OP, the OP got it working:

```
section .bss
    vfd resb 5
    vfn resb 15
    vdlen resb 5
    vdata resw 10
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,vfn
    mov dword [eax],'test'
    mov dword [eax+4],'.txt'
    mov ebx,vdata
    mov dword [vdata], 'Hell'
    mov dword [vdata+4],0 ;nullbyte ? 
    mov word [vdlen],4
    jmp WriteFile
ProgramEnd:
       mov eax,1
       mov ebx,[err]
       int 80h
WriteFile:
      mov eax,5 ; open syscall
      mov ebx,vfn
      mov ecx, 65 ; Write Only, Create Only File Mode
      mov edx, 420 ; ugo: RW-R-R
      int 80h
      mov [vfd],eax
      mov eax,4
      mov ebx,[vfd]
      mov ecx,vdata
      mov edx,[vdlen]
      int 80h
      mov byte [err],0 ;this essentially does nothing since write()
      ;returns the number of bytes written so I can't actually get an
      ;error code unless I want to check for err == 0 or 
      ;err >= expectedWriteSize
      jmp ProgramEnd
```

TL;DR: OP was trying to cram 6 bytes into 4 bytes using DWORD MOV's and had mis-specified the size for vdlen.